# CSS para styled-components

Tags: css, react, react-native, styled-components

Olá, queria saber se tem como usar a tag para selecionar todos os elementos, que em css é * mas no styled-components.

EX:

```
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

Aqui ele adiciona border-box e a cor de fundo para branco a todos os elementos da pagina. E eu quero fazer igual mas com styled-components.

Comment: você pode usar o createGlobalStyle pra esse caso.

https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

para isso, existe uma função do pŕoprio `styled-components` para a criação de estados globais da aplicação. A `createGlobalStyle`.

```
// globalStyles.js
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
 
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     background-color: #fff;
   }
`;
 
export default GlobalStyle;
```

A função retorna um componente que deve ser utilizado na sua aplicação, geralmente no componente mais global possível. Ou seja, no  (caso tenha utilizado o Create React App, é claro).

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import GlobalStyle from './ui/globalStyle';
import Content from './components/Content';

function App() {
    return (
      <>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Content />
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Ao utilizar esse "estilo global", o css será aplicado em sua aplicação.